# mysql_real_escape_string function

Tags: php, mysql

I have page for login in.
when i dont use mysql_real_escape_string with username and password. No problem.

But when i use mysql_real_escape_string with username and password i cant enter to index page and i get page not found, and when i refresh page i get select * from login where username= '' and password = '' wrong

Form page

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="w.php" method="post">

Username :
<input type = "text" name="username" />
<br />
Pass :
<input type = "password" name = "password" />

<input type="submit" vale = "ok">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
} else {
?>
<html>
<body>
you are login
<a href ="logout.php">logout</a>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

and web page is

```
<?php
session_start();
$_POST = array_map('removeSlashes',$_POST);
 function removeSlashes($value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        $value = array_map('removeSlashes',$value);
    } else {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
        }
return $value;
 }

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'a12345');
$db   ='sess1';
$select = mysql_select_db($db);
$username  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$query= "select * from login where username= '$username' and password = '$password' ";
echo "$query";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0) { 
    $_SESSION['username'] = true;
    header('location:index.php');
} else {
    echo "wrong";
}
?>
```

Comment: You've got "page not found" error when you only add mysql_real_escape_string()? I don't believe that this causes the problem.

Comment: @MarcelBalzer yes. when i use same this code i get page not found. but when i remove it the page open and i get you are login

Comment: OMG you have taken password fields type text. I can't believe it.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ i change it to password.but same problem

Comment: @user3264926 you need to check the `if(isset($_POST))` at the starting of the code in w.php file.

Comment: This may not be the cause of your problem, but you cant use header() after you've printed something ( $query ).

Comment: can u please print $_POST array after removeslashes function. you have to start a connection before you can escape data. so make sure error reporting is on and you have working conenction

Comment: **Don't use** mysql_real_escape_string() function anymore. Try **PDO** or **Mysqli** then you don't need such functions. block header, echo the received values of $_POST to ensure is it got it correctly, check it after escaped string, check the query.

Comment: Are you sure that you have entered correct location path for `index.php`(you may have named `form.php` instead) file in the `header` function. That may be the reason for `404` error.

Comment: @Patrick header() tags could be used after output is added if output_buffering is on in php.ini. (but it's not advised)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are describing cant possibly derive from adding mysql_real_escape_string(). Since this function only escapes "mysql characters".

So your problem must be some where else.

One thing you should change is (Add a space character after location):

```
header('location: index.php');
```

Also you schould not use mysql* functions since this are depracted. Look in to mysqli or PDO instead!

**EDIT**

After looking deeper at your code. much of it is a violation of best practices. I suggest that you start from the beginning following a good tutorial.

Maybe one of those bellow: 
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL
http://webcodingtutorial.blogspot.se/2013/05/php-mysqli-secure-login-page-with.html
http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=135287

All of them uses different mysqli solutions.

If you like you could also search and use a PDO example or something else. But i strongly advise that you don't use mysql*

Comment: i make space . still problem

Answer (score 0):

replace `mysql_affected_rows()` with `mysql_num_rows()` because

```
int mysql_affected_rows ([ resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

Get the number of affected rows by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query associated with link_identifier.

```
int mysql_num_rows ( resource $result )
```

Retrieves the number of rows from a result set. This command is only valid for statements like SELECT or SHOW that return an actual result set

**Notice**

Remember that `mysql_` functions are deprecated. You should use `mysqli_` instead

Comment: add `var_dump($_POST);` before `mysql_real_escape_string` calls; and `var_dump($username, $password);` after

Answer (score -1):

php is below.

```
<?php
session_start();

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'a12345');
 $db   ='sess1';
  $select = mysql_select_db($db);
 $username  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
 $password  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

 $query= "select * from login where username= '".$username."' and password = '".$password."' ";
  echo "$query";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

  if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0) { 
     $_SESSION['username'] = true;
     header("Location: index.php");
  } else {
    echo "wrong";
  }
```

Comment: I have updated the code ... and can you please post the which error you are getting